# How to evaluate the following prefix expression?

Tags: education

Can you please help in evaluating following prefix expression? Thank you.

– ^ / + + 4 6 2 – 4 1 2 9

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to evaluate prefix expression is a stack. If you have not heard of it before, it is easy to understand anyways, as I will show.

We will process your expression `– ^ / + + 4 6 2 – 4 1 2 9` in reverse order, while maintaining a list of numbers. Every time we see a number, we *append* it to the end of the list. If we see an operand (`+ - * / ^`), we will calculate the result using the last two numbers in our list, remove the two numbers, and append the result instead.

---

Below, I will process each token of your expression one by one, while keeping track of the list.

1. Token = `9`, append to list, list = `[9]`
2. Token = `2`, append to list, list = `[9, 2]`
3. Token = `1`, append to list, list = `[9, 2, 1]`
4. Token = `4`, append to list, list = `[9, 2, 1, 4]`
5. Token = `-`, *calculate result using* $4$ and $1$, giving us $4 - 1 = 3$, and we append 3: list = `[9, 2, 3]`
6. Token = `2`, append to list, list = `[9, 2, 3, 2]`
7. Token = `6`, append to list, list = `[9, 2, 3, 2, 6]`
8. Token = `4`, append to list, list = `[9, 2, 3, 2, 6, 4]`
9. Token = `+`, calculate `6 + 4`, list = `[9, 2, 3, 2, 10]`
10. Token = `+`, calculate `2 + 10`, list = `[9, 2, 3, 12]`
11. Token = `/`, calculate `12 / 3`, list = `[9, 2, 4]`
12. Token = `^`, calculate `4 ^ 2`, list = `[9, 16]`
13. Token = `-`, calculate `16 - 9`, list = `[7]`

As you can see, the result is `7`. If at any point the list is empty (i.e. "adding one number"), then the expression is invalid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I put in brackets everywhere first, starting with each operation and enclosing two arguments

```
   – ^ / + + 4 6 2 – 4 1 2 9 
= (– (^ (/ (+ (+ 4 6) 2) (– 4 1)) 2) 9)
```

Generally the arguments are single digit numbers, apart from where the minus sign appears; in this case the result of the minus operation is an argument.

Hopefully from here it should be straight-forward to see what to do. One way would be to convert everything into infix notation;

```
 (– (^ (/ (+ (+ 4 6) 2) (– 4 1)) 2) 9)
= (((4+6)+2)/(4-1))^2 - 9
= 7
```

Or you could go through and evaluate the prefix operations one by one, like Gareth Ma's answer.